# Duplicates for list of objects and aggregate in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of 3 rows, comparing them with each other on certain condition to check if they match with any. If they match, need to aggregate the sum of inner list.

Below is the list I have. Need to check if the values of Property1, Property2 and Property3 (which is in InnerList) are same. If same, need to add the Percentage Column in inner list for the particular Property3 value

```
{
List:[
{
Property1: "Apple",
Property2: "Fruit",
    InnerList:[{Property3 : 100,Percentage: 50.00}]
},
{
Property1: "Apple",
Property2: "Fruit",
    InnerList:[{Property3 : 100,Percentage: 50.00},
               {Property3 : 50,Percentage: 50.00}]
},
{
Property1: "Mango",
Property2: "Fruit",
    InnerList:[{Property3 : 75,Percentage: 50.00}]
}
]}
```

Tried using Distinct() which didn't work. and also tried the below query which is used to add values for Property3 but not sure how to add condition to inner list and get the below result.

```
Query used:

var result = list
.GroupBy(x=> new {x.Property1,x.Property2})
.Select(grp => new Class
{
Property1 = grp.Key.Property1,
Property2 = grp.Key.Property2,
innerList = new List<InnerList>
{
new InnerList
{
   Percentage = grp.SelectMany(x=> x.innerList).Sum(x=>x.Percentage)
}
}
}).ToList();
```

```
{
List:[
{
Property1: "Apple",
Property2: "Fruit",
    InnerList:[{Property3 : 100,Percentage: 100.00},
               {Property3 : 50,Percentage: 50.00}]
},
{
Property1: "Mango",
Property2: "Fruit",
    InnerList:[{Property3 : 75,Percentage: 50.00}]
}
]}
```

Comment: You'll want to [override the equality members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) in the class that's getting added to both of these lists. If you have ReSharper or Rider, it can do this for you. If not, you'll have to do it manually which is a bit of a pain but not too bad. You would check if the inner list is the same within the equality members of the object containing it.

Comment: To check if lists are the same once you've overridden the object's equality members, you can order the list then use [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-7.0). You could also combine the two lists you're comparing, use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) to group them, then check how many are in each group. If they're all 2, they're equal. If there's any with only 1, they're not. You could also just loop through and check if "manually" if you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to group by `Property1` and `Property2` and then use `SelectMany` to flatten the inner lists. Then you can use `GroupBy` again to group by `Property3` and sum the `Percentage` values.

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Property1, x.Property2 })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Property1,
        g.Key.Property2,
        InnerList = g.SelectMany(x => x.InnerList)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Property3)
            .Select(g2 => new InnerList
            {
                Property3 = g2.Key,
                Percentage = g2.Sum(x => x.Percentage)
            })
    });
```